# Terragrunt CICD init failure via GitHub Actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terragrunt

I'm having some difficulty attempting to run terragrunt via CI/CD using Github Actions. I get the below error message. Upon investigation, i found that this has been reported by others and relates to dependency blocks.

I have tried the recommended actions of adding mock outputs, merging the mock outputs to state, upgrading/downgrading the version of terragrunt, introducing a Makefile to 'cd' into each directory and run an init, plan and apply (as there seem to be issues with the run-all command).

I am able to successfully deploy the terragrunt resources in a particular order using CLI due to dependencies. The VPC and Hosted Zone need to be setup first as they have no dependencies. Currently, the resources are setup by CLI and the state file exists, so I any subsequent run of the CI/CD pipeline would work, but it still fails. Both CLI and Pipeline have the same version of terraform and terragrunt installed. On switching version of terragrunt i observed the **invalid character 'c'** changes to an **invalid character ':'**.

Has anybody experienced this and managed to find a fix? or is there advice on how to better set this up? Am i better off getting rid of terragrunt?

**1. Error message**

```
********** Running init for dns_records **********
time=2023-05-29T17:05:33Z level=warning msg=No double-slash (//) found in source URL /***************/terraform-aws-hosted-zone.git. Relative paths in downloaded Terraform code may not work. prefix=[/runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/hosted_zone] 
time=2023-05-29T17:05:35Z level=error msg=Could not parse output from terragrunt config /runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/hosted_zone/terragrunt.hcl. Underlying error: invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value
time=2023-05-29T17:05:35Z level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
********** Running init for subnet/mft-subnet **********
time=2023-05-29T17:05:35Z level=warning msg=No double-slash (//) found in source URL /***************/terraform-aws-vpc.git. Relative paths in downloaded Terraform code may not work. prefix=[/runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/vpc] 
time=2023-05-29T17:05:37Z level=error msg=Could not parse output from terragrunt config /runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/vpc/terragrunt.hcl. Underlying error: invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value
time=2023-05-29T17:05:37Z level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
********** Running init for tgw-attach **********
time=2023-05-29T17:05:37Z level=warning msg=No double-slash (//) found in source URL /***************/terraform-aws-vpc.git. Relative paths in downloaded Terraform code may not work. prefix=[/runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/vpc] 
time=2023-05-29T17:05:39Z level=error msg=Could not parse output from terragrunt config /runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/vpc/terragrunt.hcl. Underlying error: invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value
time=2023-05-29T17:05:39Z level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
********** Running init for route/tgw **********
time=2023-05-29T17:05:40Z level=warning msg=No double-slash (//) found in source URL /***************/terraform-aws-vpc.git. Relative paths in downloaded Terraform code may not work. prefix=[/runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/vpc] 
time=2023-05-29T17:05:41Z level=error msg=Could not parse output from terragrunt config /runner/_work/******-infra-terraform/******-infra-terraform/environments/preprod-******/vpc/terragrunt.hcl. Underlying error: invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value
time=2023-05-29T17:05:41Z level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
make: *** [Makefile:14: init] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

**2. Directory Structure**

```
.
├── Makefile
├── common.hcl
├── dns_records
│   ├── config.hcl
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── env.hcl
├── hosted_zone
│   ├── config.hcl
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── route
│   └── tgw
│       ├── config.hcl
│       └── terragrunt.hcl
├── subnet
│   └── mft-subnet
│       ├── config.hcl
│       └── terragrunt.hcl
├── tgw-attach
│   ├── config.hcl
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
└── vpc
    ├── config.hcl
    ├── override.tf
    └── terragrunt.hcl
```

**3. Makefile**

The pipeline first runs a task for 'make init', then 'make plan' and finally 'make apply' but doesn't get past the make init.

```
CURRENT_DIR := $(shell pwd)

MODULES := hosted_zone vpc dns_records subnet/mft-subnet tgw-attach route/tgw

.PHONY: check

check:
    @echo "please specify rule"

all: init plan apply

.PHONY: init
init:
    @for module in $(MODULES); do \
        echo "********** Running init for $$module **********"; \
        cd $(CURRENT_DIR)/$$module && terragrunt init; \
    done

.PHONY: plan
plan:
    @for module in $(MODULES); do \
        echo "********** Running plan for $$module **********"; \
        cd $(CURRENT_DIR)/$$module && terragrunt plan; \
    done

.PHONY: apply
apply:
    @for module in $(MODULES); do \
        echo "********** Running apply for $$module **********"; \
        cd $(CURRENT_DIR)/$$module && terragrunt apply -auto-approve; \
    done
```

**4. terragrunt.hcl for dns_records**

```
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

dependency "hosted_zone" {
  config_path                             = "../hosted_zone"
  mock_outputs_merge_strategy_with_state  = true
  mock_outputs_allowed_terraform_commands = ["validate", "fmt", "init", "plan"]
  mock_outputs = {
    zone_id = "zone-id"
  }

}

locals {
  # Load the data from common.hcl
  common = read_terragrunt_config("../common.hcl")
  env    = read_terragrunt_config("../env.hcl")
  config = read_terragrunt_config("config.hcl")

}

# Set the generate config dynamically to the generate config in common.hcl
generate = local.common.generate

terraform {
  source = "git::git@github.com:***************/terraform-aws-route53-record.git?ref=master"
}

inputs = {

  zone_id = dependency.hosted_zone.outputs.zone_id
  records = local.config.locals.records
  tags    = local.env.locals.tags

}
```

**5. Workflow.yml**

```
name: Linting & Validating

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - edited
      - synchronize
      - reopened
    branches:
      - "master"

  # Allow to trigger manually
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  tf_version: 'latest'
  tg_version: 'latest'
  tf_working_dir: '.'
  GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "echo '${{ secrets.GH_PRIVATE_KEY }}' > id_rsa
              && ssh-keyscan github.com > known_hosts
              && chmod 600 id_rsa known_hosts
              && ssh -i ./id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts"
              
jobs:
  check-pr:
    name: check-pr
    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        include:
          - { env: "preprod", home: "environments/preprod-********"}
    steps:
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.IE_********_TERRAFORM_USER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.IE_********_TERRAFORM_USER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2
          role-duration-seconds: 900

      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Terragrunt
        uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.3.1
        with:
          terragrunt_version: 0.42.5

      - name: Print Terragrunt Version
        run: terragrunt --version

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.19.1

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.4.5

      - name: Print Terraform Version
        run: terraform --version

      - name: 'Terragrunt Format'
        run: |
          cd ${{ matrix.home }}
          terragrunt hclfmt --terragrunt-check

      - name: 'Terragrunt Init'
        run: |
          cd ${{ matrix.home }}
          make init

      - name: 'Terragrunt Plan'          
        run: |
          cd ${{ matrix.home }}
          make plan
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the above issue was caused by the terraform_wrapper flag. Because i was using the `hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2` from the GitHub marketplace, by default terraform_wrapper is set to "true". As soon as i added the `terraform_wrapper: false` per below in my GitHub Actions workflow.yml file, it resolved the issue. Thanks to Brian on another thread for pointing this out.

```
steps:
- uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
  with:
    terraform_wrapper: false
```